# Start process with Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, vsix

I am developing an extension for Visual Studio.

I would like a feature of this extension to be the ability to start a process with a debugger attached.

So far I can get the debugger to attach using code:

```cs
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

DTE dte = ServiceProvider.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE)).Result as DTE;

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    FileName = "PATH_TO_DOT_NET_EXECUTABLE"
};
var process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

foreach (EnvDTE.Process proc in dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses)
{
    if (proc.ProcessID == process.Id)
    {
        proc.Attach();
        return;
    }

}
```

Sometimes however, the process finishes before the debugger can attach.

Is there a way to create the process from within the Visual Studio Extension in such a way that the debugger is attached upon creation?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to automatically attach the process when it starts in visual studio extension. If so, you could install the this extension: [ReAttach](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErlandR.ReAttach), which will help you start the process and attach to it as soon as it becomes available.

Comment: I suspect the API you're looking for is the IVsDebugger2.LaunchDebugTargets2 method.